# Rotina diária cakephp 2x

Tags: cakephp

Como eu faria para criar uma rotina diária, para que todo dia ele executasse uma procedure?
Faria isso via linux(crontab)? ou existe uma maneira diferente e mais prática?

Comment: Você precisa mesmo utilizar o `Cron Jobs`, agora o que é exatamente esta *procedure* que você se refere? É um processo que você desenvolveu com o *Cake*? Neste caso você pode utilizar [`Shells` e programar a rotina](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html).

Answer (score 1):

O ideal é fazer em Shell pra não consumir recurso do apache/ngnix e executar ele como cron do linux.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html

Tenho costume de fazer dessa forma acima.